# Moving a body from one position to another on button press

Tags: andengine

I have a problem where the player releases a power attack,this powerattack must move upto a certain position and then get detached,how can i achieve this? I tried using setvelocity but it didnt work that well...pls help!!

Ok here's my attack method which is called when the button is pressed:

public void powerattack() {

```
    float startBulletX = player.getX() + 30; //Get X position of character body
    float startBulletY = player.getY();      //Get Y position of character body

    final Sprite bullet = new Sprite(startBulletX, startBulletY,
            resourcesManager.special_attack, vbom);  //The special attack sprite

    final FixtureDef bulletFixtureDef1 = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0,
            0, 0, false, CATEGORYBIT_KNIFE, MASKBIT_KNIFE, (short) 0);
    this.mBulletBody = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physicsWorld, bullet,
            BodyType.DynamicBody, bulletFixtureDef1);  

    mBulletBody.setLinearVelocity(20f,0);

    this.physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(bullet,
            this.mBulletBody, true, false));


    this.attachChild(bullet);  

}
```

When i run this code the special attack body moves out of screen...I want to limit the power attack to a certain position i.e few distance away from the character.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution,I used onUpdate method and within that onupdate method i set the code as invisible,here's my code :)

```
public void powerattack() {

    float startBulletX = player.getX() + 30;
    float startBulletY = player.getY();

    final Sprite ray = new Sprite(startBulletX, startBulletY,
            resourcesManager.special_attack, vbom);
    final Vector2 velocity = Vector2Pool.obtain(20f, 0);
    final FixtureDef rayFixtureDef1 = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0,
            0, false, CATEGORYBIT_RAY, MASKBIT_RAY, (short) 0);
    this.mRayBody = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physicsWorld, ray,
            BodyType.DynamicBody, rayFixtureDef1);

    this.mRayBody.setLinearVelocity(velocity);
    Vector2Pool.recycle(velocity);

    this.physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(ray,
            this.mRayBody, true, false) {
        /*Update method keeps checking whether the power attack reached the specific distance*/
        @Override
        public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {

            if (ray.getX() >= (player.getX() + 300)) {

                ray.setVisible(false);
                ray.setIgnoreUpdate(false);

            }
            super.onUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
            camera.onUpdate(0.1f);
        }
    });

    mRayBody.setUserData("power");
    this.attachChild(ray);

}
```